# Why does this scanf in a while loop work?

Tags: c, while-loop, scanf

I can't understand why this does exactly what I want. The part where I used two scanf's in the loop confuses me. I compiled it using devcpp.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int dend, dsor, q, r;
    char c;
    while(c!='n')
    {
        printf("enter dividend: ");
        scanf("%d", &dend);
        printf("enter divisor: ");
        scanf("%d", &dsor);
        q=dend/dsor;
        r=dend%dsor;
        printf("quotient is %d\n", q);
        printf("remainder is %d\n", r);
        scanf("%c", &c);
        printf("continue? (y/n)\n");
        scanf("%c", &c);
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: where is `do...while`?

Comment: This is no "explain my code" site. What is your problem? Did you read the man-pages of the functions?

Comment: Consider what happened to the trailing newline that remained in the input stream after you finished extracting your *second* number. A debugger and some single-stepping would probably have helped significantly here.

Comment: Related: The reason why the solution [to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36284545/1322972) (and *hundreds* like it) works is to avoid the otherwise brittle solution you have here. For example, when entering your second number, add a blank space, *then* hit enter on your keyboard and see what happens.

Comment: You could and probably should use a single `scanf(" %c", &c);` call after the 'continue' prompt.  The leading space reads newlines and leading blanks etc.  You should check each and every `scanf()` to ensure you get the correct number of values converted successfully (`if (scanf(…) == 1)` happens to be correct in this code in each case, but you should check for the expected number of values).

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, your code invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). In the part

```
char c;
while(c!='n')
```

`c` is an uninitialized local variable with automatic storage and you're trying to use the value of `c` while it is indeterminate.

That said, first `scanf("%c", &c);` is used to *eat up* the newline present in the input buffer due to the press of enter key after previous input. [You can read about it in details in another post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29658685/2173917).