# scanf function not working with characters

Tags: c, arrays, scanf

I was just trying out a simple program in C, inserting into an array.
I used a `scanf` function to accept characters but it seems the compiler just skipped that and just went to end of the program.
This was the code that I used :-

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int a[50], i, j, m, n, x;
    char ch;
    printf("Enter the no. elements of the array :- ");
    scanf("%d", &m);
    printf("Enter the elements below :- ");
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }
    printf("The array is :- \n");
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\nDo you want to enter an element ? (Y/N)\n");
    scanf("%c", &ch);       // The compiler just skips this along with the      
    while (ch == 'y' || ch == 'Y') // while loop and goes straight to the printf 
    {                   // statement
        printf("The index of the element :- ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        printf("\nEnter a number :- ");
        scanf("%d", &x);
        for (i = m; i > n; i--)
        {
            a[i] = a[i - 1];
        }
        a[n] = x;
        printf("\nInsert more numbers ? (Y/N)");
        scanf("%c", &ch);
        m = m + 1;
    }
    printf("\nThe array is :- ");
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", a[i]);
    }
}
```

I used the variable `ch` in order to allow the user to have a choice, whether or not to insert elements i.e. `Y` or `N`.

But the compiler basically skips the third `scanf` function, the one that accepts the `char`, along with the `while` loop.

I just want to know why the `scanf` function was skipped ?

Comment: Please change `scanf("%c",&ch);` to `scanf(" %c",&ch);` so at to consume the newline left in the buffer. Unlike other formats, `%c` does not automatically skip whitespace in the input buffer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scanf Skip scanning character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36281871/scanf-skip-scanning-character)

Comment: ....and please post well indented code...

Comment: The compiler doesn't care about the keys you press. It only produces an executable program from your source code. This executable program (and the source code you compiled to generate it) is responsible for correct handling of the input. Your code that reads the numbers doesn't consume the newlines produced when you press `<Enter>`, the newline is then read by the next `scanf("%c")` and this is the reason the code doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Possible Duplicate Of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669821/scanf-skips-every-other-while-loop-in-c

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Back to the previous `scanf` which is the last array member.

```
scanf("%d",&a[i])
```

In the input file if you entered:

```
32\n 
^^
```

input will wait just before the newline after reading the decimal number.

In the `scanf` which causes problem:

```
scanf("%c", &ch);
```

It will read the newline character as it is **available** in **input** that's why it will skip that line after being executed implicitly.

To ignore the whitespace you have only to add space before the specifier `%c` as stated in comment by @xing and @WeatherVane.

```
scanf(" %c",&ch);
```

**C99 7.19.6.2**

> **Input white-space characters** (as specified by the isspace function)
>   are **skipped**, **unless** the specification includes a [, **c**, or n
>   specifier.250)

Comment: Good answer +1. But consider to use tons of previous answers as duplicate

Comment: This question is also duplicate but it seems that there is no good understanding of `scanf` from OP

Comment: "It will read the newline character as it is available in input that's why it will skip it.

To ignore the whitespaces"                                                                         I didn't quite get that. Could you please elaborate as to why the scanf function skipps since there is a \n present before it.

Comment: `scanf` read from input file which is `stdin`. As long as it find the required characters in the file and the correct format it will read those characters **directly** without your intervention. When input file is **empty** it will wait for user to fill the input file with required characters. In your case, after reading the decimal number you entered newline which will stay in input file so for the next `scanf` you require a character and as newline is a character it will read it from input that's why it will be skipped.